# How to send unique test data per request on BlazeMeter for all active Virtual Users without duplication?

Tags: csv, jmeter, unique, blazemeter, test-data

My test data CSV file has 2 columns, with `uniqueId` and `names` (for example).

I'm trying to run with 2 Load Generators (25 Virtual Users each).

I need the test to send uniqueId's for every single transactions that are sent.
During the session the uniqueId gets locked until the completion of transaction, then only that same uniqueId can be resued.
If the same uniqueId (in session) is used by another Virtual User, the transaction will fail.

I am struggling to find a way to ensure that all the Virtual Users in session are utilising only unique test data (uniqueId) without duplication.

Any help is appreciated.

What I've tried:

I've tried setting below in CSV Data Set Config in jmeter script with no luck, but I'm looking solutions for Blazemeter:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNYUb.png)
Recycle on EOF? False
Stop thread on EOF? True
Sharing mode: All threads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think questions like this should go to [BlazeMeter Support](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207491229-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket) as these guys should know the product better than anyone here.

However if you prefer community answers: take a look at [CSV File Upload](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420585-CSV-File-Upload) article of BlazeMeter documentation.

**Run a multi-engines test with a single CSV file** chapter says:

> Enable the 'Split CSV files' checkbox, and when the test is initiating, the CSV file will be split 5 ways and each unique subset will be directed to a different engine

[image]

This along with Sharing Mode of "All threads" will guarantee the "uniqueness" of the ID assuming you have less virtual users than lines in the CSV file.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri! I will action on your suggestion.